# How to set text in HtmlUnit Span outside of an element?

Tags: java, htmlunit

I want to simulate clicking on a button in a Learning Management System, Schoology, in order to change a setting on an assignment I'm creating using Java and HtmlUnit. When I get the element and click on it, the state of it does not change (unsure why). So I'm trying to manually set the values according to what they are when the button is clicked/unclicked.

Unclicked:

```
<span tabindex="0" role="button" key="dropbox" class="adv-option-btn adv-option-toggle toggle-dropbox adv-option-on sCourseMaterialsLock-processed" on-title="Submissions Enabled" off-title="Submissions Disabled" original-title=""><span class="visually-hidden">Submissions Enabled</span></span>
```

Clicked:

```
<span tabindex="0" role="button" key="dropbox" class="adv-option-btn adv-option-toggle toggle-dropbox sCourseMaterialsLock-processed" on-title="Submissions Enabled" off-title="Submissions Disabled" original-title=""><span class="visually-hidden">Submissions Disabled</span></span>
```

This is my code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
HtmlPage currPage=webClient.getPage("https://app.schoology.com/course/*************/materials/assignments/add?f=********");

List<Object> submissionDisabler=(List<Object>) currPage.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"s-grade-item-add-form\"]/div/div[15]/div[2]/span[1]");
assert submissionDisabler.size()==1;
DomElement dom = (DomElement) submissionDisabler.get(0);

dom.setAttribute("class", "adv-option-btn adv-option-toggle toggle-dropbox sCourseMaterialsLock-processed");
dom.setTextContent("Submissions Disabled"); (also tried without this...)

DomElement submitBtn = currPage.getElementById("edit-submit"); //Find element called Submit to submit form.
currPage = submitBtn.click(); //Click on the button.
```

This successfully creates the assignment, but the button I want to be clicked (which disables submissions to the assignment) is unclicked when I enter Schoology manually and view the assignment. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean by 'unclicked' but as a general hint i think

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

might be the problem. Maybe parts of the button handling is done at the client side in java script - this requires js support to be enabled. HtmlUnit is not that bad in executing all the page js.

```
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

If this does not help please open an issue on github (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues) and i will try to analyze this in more detail.